# Ruby array of hashes max value of duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes and it consists of some duplicate keys.

```rb
array = [
 {:number=>116498,
  :account=>206161,
  :tax_id=>"320996279",
  :created=>"11/13/2015"
  },
 {:number=>116500,
  :account=>206161,
  :tax_id=>"320996279",
  :created=>"12/13/2015"
  },
 {:number=>116499,
  :account=>206161,
  :tax_id=>"320996279",
  :created=>"01/13/2015"
  },
 {:number=>116501,
  :account=>206162,
  :tax_id=>"122032382",
  :created=>"11/13/2015"
  }]
```

Notice that the key `:tax_id` has duplicate values. I want to  iterate through the array of hashes and get my output this way with the `:created` key having a max value

```rb
array = [
 {:number=>116500,
  :account=>206161,
  :tax_id=>"320996279",
  :created=>"12/13/2015"
  },
 {:number=>116501,
  :account=>206162,
  :tax_id=>"122032382",
  :created=>"11/13/2015"
 }]
```

Comment: Define how `:created` key will have the max value. String comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assuming your array is called `a`):

```
a.group_by{|el| el[:tax_id]}.values.map{|el| el.max_by{|x| x[:created]}}
```

As pointed out in the comment, this assumes max is computed with a simple string comparison, you might want to convert `created` to Date or DateTime if you want a date comparison. The following will add a `:created_date` and use that to compute the max:

```
a.each{|el| el.merge!( {created_date: Date.strptime(el[:created], '%m/%d/%Y')})}.group_by{|el| el[:tax_id]}.values.map{|el| el.max_by{|x| x[:created_date]}}
```

This works as follows:

1. We iterate through the array, adding the `:created_date` for each hash;
2. We group by `:tax_id`, this will something of the form `["tax_id_1" => [ {…}, …], "tax_id_2" => …]`;
3. We get the values only, as we do not care about the tax_ids;
4. For each array with the same tax_id, we keep only the one with the maximum `:created_date`.